# Trying to understand how mutual authentication key pairs and certificates work in a gRPC context

Tags: java, ssl, grpc, tls1.2, grpc-java

so after reading countless articles on how and what to generate key pairs, certificates, trust managers i'm incredibly confused.

This is my situation, i have a client:

```
SslContextBuilder builder = GrpcSslContexts.forClient();
// builder.trustManager(new File(trustCertCollectionFilePath)); //i've read this should be ignored for the client
builder.keyManager(new File(clientCertChainFilePath), new File(clientPrivateKeyFilePath));
```

and a server:

```
SslContextBuilder sslClientContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forServer(new 
         File(certChainFilePath), new File(privateKeyFilePath));
sslClientContextBuilder.trustManager(new File(trustCertCollectionFilePath));
sslClientContextBuilder.clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE);
```

I'm using these from an example found here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/example-tls/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworldtls

As far as I've understood it should work like this:

For the client:

```
1. You have to generate a RSA key pair.
2. Generate a certificate.
3. Put the public key inside the certificate.

clientCertChainFilePath = certificate with public key inside
clientPrivateKeyFilePath = client private key
```

For the server:

```
1. You have to generate a trusted authority certificate(CA) with a server private key
2. Get the certificate from the client
3. Register the client certificate inside the trusted authority somehow.

certChainFilePath = certificate from the client with public key inside
privateKeyFilePath = private server key for the trust authority certificate(CA)
trustCertCollectionFilePath = trusted authority certificate(CA)
```

Please correct me or tell me how exactly all of this binds together to make this work, if you have any specific links on how to generate everything properly it's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Client and server both have their own public and private keys. These are two separate pairs of public-private keys.

On the server side, `certChainFilePath` is the server certificate with server's public key inside. `privateKeyFilePath` is server's private key.

Without mutual TLS, client only needs the CA certificate to verify server's certificate received during handshake.

With mutual TLS, client is requested to send its certificate (with client public key inside) to server.